# Managing SQL scripts with arguments

Tags: sql, oracle, git

I keep many work-related SQL convenience scripts.
For a while I've been using a convention of having
several AND clauses in the where statement that I can activate
by providing a value or values to search on.  For example,

```
where color like '%&color' and size like '%&size'
```

When I run such SQL in my preferred client (Golden6) it pops up
a dialog box where I can provide values for color, size or both.
Very convenient, but the performance of LIKE '%string' is often 
terrible, often resulting in a full table scan, or so I have read.

Is there some alternative technique for writing and managing these
scripts that maintains the convenience of being able to fill in only the 
arguments I want to use, yet avoids the performance issues around LIKE '%string'?  I don't want to have to edit the script each time I use it,
because I keep them in git and I don't want to manage having a bunch of locally modified files to sort out all the time.

Comment: Well, I guess the question is, do you *really* need `LIKE`?  Are you searching for exact values that you know exist, or are you really wanting anything similar to the values you searched?  If you really need to use `LIKE '%...'`, then a full table scan cannot be avoided (it does a full table scan because of the leading wildcard, which makes an index unusable).

Comment: I'm using LIKE only as sort of a trick, so that if I (for example) do not provide a value for color, and only for size, that the empty color clause does not prevent anything from matching the where condition.

Comment: You could always change the `AND` to an `OR` to fix that, rather than using a `LIKE`

Comment: see [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17681428/issue-with-oracle-bind-variables-not-using-index-properly/17702034#17702034) for an approach you might try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to support optional input parameters then you could try

```
with data as 
(select '123' col1, 'ABC' col2 from dual union select '124', 'AB' from     dual)
select * from  data a where a.col1 = nvl('&col1', a.col1) and a.col2 = nvl('&col2', a.col2)
```

Additonal data rows with null values

```
with data as
 (select '123' col1, 'ABC' col2
from dual
  union
  select '124', 'AB'
    from dual
  union
  select '123', null from dual
  union
  select '124', null from dual)
select *
  from data
 where ('&col1' is null or '&col1' is not null and '&col1' = col1)
 and ('&col2' is null or '&col2' is not null and '&col2' = col2)
```

Comment: I had to tweak this answer to get the behavior I wanted.  Experimenting on Oracle it seems a 'value=value' condition is false if the value is null.  This means I have to say  _and (size is null or size = nvl('&size', size))_ for each of my optional input parameters.

Comment: Actually that doesn't work either: When applying that technique now I get values that either match the requested value or are null (obviously I guess).  I'm about ready to give up.

Comment: That's right. But as i expect your example with like operator will also not return null values? To get this columns the is operator is required.

Comment: my 2nd sql should solve your problem from 2nd comment. Hope it helps.

Comment: That did help, thanks.  I added another answer based on your suggestions, but in a way that I find easier to read and understand

Comment: Thanks for incorporating my feedback, I have deleted my answer and am accepting yours