# Oracle optional bind variables

Tags: oracle, query-performance, bind-variables

I have a query to select users from a table, given user id. This parameter is optional.

This is the query:

```
SELECT * FROM USERS
WHERE (USER_ID = :USER_ID OR :USER_ID IS NULL)
ORDER BY USER_ID;
```

Now I execute the query finding one user, so `:USER_ID` takes the valor 1 :

```
SELECT * FROM USERS
WHERE (USER_ID = 1 OR 1 IS NULL)
ORDER BY USER_ID;
```

*This query takes 5 seconds.*

And then, I add to the previous query `OR :USER_ID IS NULL` many times. This example takes much more time than the first:

```
SELECT * FROM USERS
WHERE (USER_ID = 1 OR 1 IS NULL [OR 1 IS NULL]x100)
ORDER BY USER_ID;
```

*This query takes 30 seconds.*

---

The **execution plan** are the same in the two examples:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                   | Name    | Rows  | Bytes |TempSpc| Cost (%CPU)| Time     | Pstart| Pstop |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT            |         |  3256K|   695M|       |   682K  (1)| 00:00:27 |       |       |
|   1 |  SORT ORDER BY              |         |  3256K|   695M|   877M|   682K  (1)| 00:00:27 |       |       |
|   2 |   PARTITION RANGE ALL       |         |  3256K|   695M|       |   534K  (1)| 00:00:21 |     1 |1048575|
|*  3 |    TABLE ACCESS STORAGE FULL| USERS |  3256K|   695M|       |   534K  (1)| 00:00:21 |     1 |1048575|
```

---

**Version of Oracle:** Oracle Database 12c

---

Why oracle does not take the first statement, that it's always true, and stop evaluating the rest?

Comment: are there index on the table ?

Comment: How many times did you run the query? Oracle has to do a hard-parse of the modified query and the first time it does this will increase the time - the second and subsequent times it can do a soft-parse and potentially retrieve the results from its cache. To compare queries you may need to either flush the result cache or run both multiple times.

Comment: I ran each query a couple of times. And always the second takes much more time.

Comment: Investigate / post the execution plans for both queries as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34975406/how-to-describe-performance-issue-in-relational-database?answertab=oldest#tab-top). You'll immediately see difference between them and probably also the *missing index on `USER_ID`*

Comment: possible [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17681428/issue-with-oracle-bind-variables-not-using-index-properly/17702034#17702034)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is the `FULL TABLE SCAN` on a large table triggered by the `OR`predicate.

Based on the value of the bind variable the query returns either one row (if the bind variable is not NULL) or the whole table otherwise.

For only one bind variable you may use the `NVL` *trick*

```
SELECT * FROM USERS
WHERE (USER_ID = nvl(:USER_ID, USER_ID))
ORDER BY USER_ID;
```

which leads to a execution plan consisting of two parts covering both cases :

BV is NULL -> FULL SCAN

BV is NOT NULL -> INDEX ACCES

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                      | Name      | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT               |           |  8329 |  9313K|   941   (1)| 00:00:12 |
|   1 |  SORT ORDER BY                 |           |  8329 |  9313K|   941   (1)| 00:00:12 |
|   2 |   CONCATENATION                |           |       |       |            |          |
|*  3 |    FILTER                      |           |       |       |            |          |
|*  4 |     TABLE ACCESS FULL          | USERS     |  8247 |  9221K|   925   (1)| 00:00:12 |
|*  5 |    FILTER                      |           |       |       |            |          |
|   6 |     TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| USERS     |    82 | 93890 |    15   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  7 |      INDEX RANGE SCAN          | USERS_IDX |  1110 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   3 - filter(:USER_ID IS NULL)
   4 - filter("USER_ID" IS NOT NULL)
   5 - filter(:USER_ID IS NOT NULL)
   7 - access("USER_ID"=:USER_ID)
```

So this will response quickly, if the BV is passed (not NULL) **AND** index on `USER_ID`is defined.
This will lead to a `FULL TABLE SCAN` (5 seconds) **AND** `SORT` of the whole table (my guess an other 25 seconds), giving total 30 seconds response.

Note that if you pass the BV, you performs only the `FULL TABLE SCAN`, the `SORT` time is neglectible as only one records is returned (assuming USER_ID is PK) - which explains the difference in the response time.