# Use like '%' and match NULL values with NUMBER columns

Tags: sql, oracle

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3924400/like-does-not-accept-null-value) is almost exactly like mine but none of the answers work with my case.

If it was my question I'd slightly edit it to make it a different question. This question is thus different from the linked one.

Here's the problem: I want a way to match any non-null value (`'%'`) AND null values.

The thing is:

- I'm using oracle so I can't use `IsNull`
- Some columns are `NUMBER`s, which means I can't use `COALESCE(column, ' ')`. (*ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected NUMBER got CHAR*). However, `like '%'` and `like '2118'` do work on NUMBER columns.

None of the answers apply to this problem because you can't make a null into an empty string when the column is a NUMBER.

How could I do to achieve this?

---

Some context:

My procedure takes a lot of parameters, and does a select with all of them. They can all have a value or be null, so if they're null they're replaced with `'%'`.

That way, the procedure does :

```
where t.col1 like param1
and t.col2 like param2
...
```

Most of the times, only one or two parameters is not null. For the others parameters, the procedure needs to match on every row.

But when the value is null, `like '%'` doesn't match the row. I'm looking for a way to match anything when param x is empty (so `paramx = '%'`)

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  Because all values are either valid or `NULL`, it sounds like you don't want any conditions at all.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I added some context. I thought it was way clearer to explain my procedure than to paste a wall of code, I hope that makes it clear enough.

Comment: `LIKE` is for character values. It's **not** for numbers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> My procedure takes a lot of parameters, and does a select with all of them. They can all have a value or be null, so if they're null they're replaced with '%'.

That seems like you're making life hard for yourself. Leave them null, then do:

```
where (param1 is null or t.col1 like param1)
and (param2 is null or t.col2 like param2)
```

If `param1` (the procedure argument; life is simpler when your parameter/variable names and column names are different... so I've changed the column names to make it a bit clearer) is null it is basically ignored* and all rows pass that part of the filter, whether the column value is null or not null. If `param2` is *not* null then the `is null` check for that fails and only rows with (not-null) column values that match `param2` value meet that part of the filter.

<sub>* Conditions in an `or` can be evaluated in any order; putting the `is null` check first doesn't necessarily mean the `like` won't be evaluated - but the optimiser is pretty smart about that sort of thing</sub>

Comment: Smart and elegant solution, thank you! Names are indeed different in my procedure but they're prefixed with something not universal at all, I thought it would be clearer to leave them out. I edited that part of the question.

Comment: I would have done it similarly, but without the "OR":  where t.col1 like nvl(param1, t.col1).  Not sure how that would affect performance, though.

Comment: My test on 12.1 shows, that even if there are indces on `col1`, `col2`and `col1,col2` I end with `TABLE ACCESS FULL` with  `filter((:PARAM1 IS NULL OR "T"."COL1" LIKE :PARAM1) AND (:PARAM2  IS NULL OR "T"."COL2" LIKE :PARAM2))`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to match a specific value and `NULL`, you can use `OR`:

```
where col = <specific value> or col is null
```

Comment: That's what I thought of first, but when `<specific value>` is not `'%'`, I don't want to match nulls.

Comment: Ok, how about where ((col1 = '%' or col1 is null) or col1='value other than %')

Answer (score 1):

In Oracle  NVL can be used instead of ISNULL

```
IF NVL(aNumberColumn,-1) = -1 THEN
    ---whatever
END IF;
```

Answer (score 0):

Oracle automatically converts `NUMBER` to `VARCHAR2` for like-conditions. So what you have todo is do that yourself so you can use coalesce:

```
COALESCE(TO_CHAR(column), ' ') like '%'
```

Comment: That's what I did but I got an error from Oracle when the column is a `NUMBER`.

Comment: I added explicit conversion to_char, so the error will not accure any more. Wanted to be as close to your attempt as possible. Wasn't clear if you needed the `like` functionality along with `null`- checks. If not better use `(column is null or column = :1)`...

Answer (score 0):

The proposals from other answers based on `OR` or `NVL`/ `COALESCE` are "elegant" and simple, but as a rule they inhibit the index access, which is the most important thing.

You may step down to use *dynamic SQL* to address the *optional parameter* problem - which is your case. If a parameter is not passed (it is NULL) - simple ignore it.

So for example with two parameters, if both parameters are passed, generate following SQL

```
select * from tab t
where t.col1 like :param1
and t.col2 like :param2
```

If only parameter 1 is given, generate this SQL:

```
select * from tab t
where t.col1 like :param1
```

With no parameter you will end with

```
select * from tab t
```

Technically it is preferable to have in all SQL statements the *same number of bind variables*, which is not the case in the above proposal. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57653954/4808122) for detailed explanation of the trick popularized by Tom Kyte to preserve the number of bind variable with optional parameters.

For example the second statement with only *parameter 1* would yield following SQL

```
select * from tab t
where t.col1 like :param1
and (1=1 or t.col2 like :param2)
```

The shortcut logik of `1=1`(which is TRUE) eliminates the second part of the predicate, but the bind variable is still used, so the number of the bind variables remains constant.

**The big advantage is a fine index range access of this query**