# Is there a way to dynamically set SELECT Query for a FOR LOOP

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

What i am trying is to iterate through a SELECT based on a certain condition.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE procedure
IS
selectForLoop varchar2(256);
v_birthdate date;
BEGIN
select X into v_birthdate from Y where C = Z;
IF true THEN
   selectForLoop := 'Select name from employees';
ELSE
   selectForLoop := 'Select name from employees where birthdate = v_birthdate';
END IF;

FOR val in (selectForLoop)
LOOP
   BusinessLogic
END LOOP;
```

What i could do is:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE procedure
IS
v_birthdate date;
BEGIN 
select X into v_birthdate from Y where C = Z;
If true THEN
   FOR i IN (Select name from employees)
   LOOP
      BusinessLogic
   END LOOP;
ELSE
   FOR i IN (Select name from employees where birthdate = v_birthdate
   LOOP
      BusinessLogic
   END LOOP;
END IF;
```

That would be a solution but the businesslogic is the same in both ways and only the data that i want to iterate through is different. Id really like to prevent that dirty copypasta attempt.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [cursors](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/lnpls/static-sql.html#GUID-F1FE15F9-5C96-4C4E-B240-B7363D25A8F1) and [cursor variables](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/lnpls/static-sql.html#GUID-4A6E054A-4002-418D-A1CA-DE849CD7E6D5) in PL/SQL to dynamically switch between queries.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE procedure
IS
  selectForLoop varchar2(256);
  v_name employees%name%TYPE;
  v_birthdate date;
  v_cursor SYS_REFCURSOR;
BEGIN
  IF condition THEN
    OPEN v_cursor FOR SELECT name FROM employees;
  ELSE
    OPEN v_cursor FOR SELECT name FROM employees WHERE birthdate = 
 v_birthdate;
  END IF;

  LOOP
    FETCH v_cursor INTO v_name;
    EXIT WHEN v_cursor%NOTFOUND;
    BusinessLogic;
  END LOOP;
  CLOSE v_cursor;
END;
```

You could also pass the cursor variable as a parameter to your business logic, and move the loop inside the business logic procedure:

```
OPEN v_cursor FOR selectForLoop;
BusinessLogic(v_cursor);
CLOSE v_cursor;


CREATE OR REPLACE
PROCEDURE BusinessLogic(p_cursor SYS_REFCURSOR IN) IS
  v_name employees%name%TYPE;
BEGIN
  LOOP
    FETCH p_cursor INTO v_name;
    EXIT WHEN p_cursor%NOTFOUND;
    -- Do business logic
  END LOOP;
END;
```

Comment: @MarmiteBomber Rewrote to avoid use of strings altogether.

Answer (score 1):

You have two *objectives*

1. keep the code `DRY` and
2. use **bind variables**

If you have only a very simple condition (as in your example, use filter or use no filter)  you my use `IF` statement to open *different* cursors for both cases.

```
IF salary_from is null THEN
  OPEN v_cursor FOR SELECT LAST_NAME, SALARY FROM hr.employees;
ELSE
  OPEN v_cursor FOR SELECT LAST_NAME, SALARY FROM hr.employees WHERE SALARY >= salary_from;
END IF;
```

Note that you should be *carefull* with the `OR` *solution* using the predicate `SALARY >= salary_from OR salary_from  is NULL`

Why?  You use *one query* for two very different scenarios. The cursor can returns either all data or very limited data, that could require a *different*  access method (e.g. index access vs full table scan). So you *may* and with suboptimal plan in one case.

The problem with the above approach is that **it does not scale**. If you have four optional criteria you will need 16-fold `IF` with a highly redundant code.

What is the solution to keep the above objectives valid?

Use *dynamic SQL*, but **do not** concatenate the criteria values such as

```
 SELECT LAST_NAME, SALARY FROM hr.employees WHERE salary >= 1000 and salary <= 10000
```

This will invalidate the bind variable objective!

To keep with the example with optional parameter *salary_from* and *salary_to* you want to use

```
open v_cursor for v_sql using salary_from, salary_to;
```

But this requires, that *both* bind variables must be defined in the query text - what should be done in case you have only *salary_from*?

Opening the cursor for this query

```
SELECT LAST_NAME, SALARY FROM hr.employees WHERE SALARY >= :salary_from
```

will lead to error

```
ORA-01006: bind variable does not exist
```

The trick is to use *dummy* predicates returning always `true`, but containing a bind variable (that will be ignored).

So if you have only *salary_from* as a filter you will create following dynamic SQL

```
SELECT LAST_NAME, SALARY FROM hr.employees WHERE SALARY >= :salary_from AND  (1=1 or SALARY <= :salary_to)
```

It contains both bind variables and the *optimizer* (with the *shortcut evaluation) will simplify it to the required

```
SELECT LAST_NAME, SALARY FROM hr.employees WHERE SALARY >= :salary_from
```

So the relevant code for the salary filter example would be

```
IF salary_from is NOT null THEN
  v_sql := 'SELECT LAST_NAME, SALARY FROM hr.employees WHERE SALARY >= :salary_from';
ELSE
  v_sql := 'SELECT LAST_NAME, SALARY FROM hr.employees WHERE (1 = 1 or SALARY >= :salary_from)';  
END IF;
IF salary_to is NOT null THEN
  v_sql := v_sql ||' AND  SALARY <= :salary_to';
ELSE
  v_sql := v_sql ||' AND  (1=1 or SALARY <= :salary_to)';  
END IF;
open v_cursor for v_sql using salary_from, salary_to;
```

Below the overview of the generated SQL for the four cases

```
-- no filter
SELECT LAST_NAME, SALARY FROM hr.employees WHERE (1 = 1 or SALARY >= :salary_from) AND  (1=1 or SALARY <= :salary_to)
-- salary_from 
SELECT LAST_NAME, SALARY FROM hr.employees WHERE SALARY >= :salary_from AND  (1=1 or SALARY <= :salary_to)
-- salary from, to
SELECT LAST_NAME, SALARY FROM hr.employees WHERE SALARY >= :salary_from AND  SALARY <= :salary_to
-- salary_to
SELECT LAST_NAME, SALARY FROM hr.employees WHERE (1 = 1 or SALARY >= :salary_from) AND  SALARY <= :salary_to
```

Similar topics with credit to this idea: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57653954/4808122), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56778621/4808122) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57895363/4808122)

Answer (score 0):

You can check for a argument being NULL in your query. Example (based on the sample data emp/dept)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE list_employees (hired_after_i DATE DEFAUlT NULL)
AS
BEGIN
  FOR r IN 
    (SELECT * FROM emp 
      WHERE hiredate > hired_after_i OR 
            hired_after_i IS NULL)
  LOOP
    dbms_output.put_line(r.ename||' hired on '||r.hiredate);
  END LOOP;
END;
/
Procedure LIST_EMPLOYEES compiled

set serveroutput on size 999999
BEGIN
  list_employees;
END;
/

SMITH hired on 17-DEC-1980
ALLEN hired on 20-FEB-1981
WARD hired on 22-FEB-1981
JONES hired on 02-APR-1981
MARTIN hired on 28-SEP-1981
BLAKE hired on 01-MAY-1981
CLARK hired on 09-JUN-1981
SCOTT hired on 19-APR-1987
KING hired on 17-NOV-1981
TURNER hired on 08-SEP-1981
ADAMS hired on 23-MAY-1987
JAMES hired on 03-DEC-1981
FORD hired on 03-DEC-1981
MILLER hired on 23-JAN-1982

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

BEGIN
  list_employees(hired_after_i => DATE'1982-01-01');
END;
/
SCOTT hired on 19-APR-1987
ADAMS hired on 23-MAY-1987
MILLER hired on 23-JAN-1982

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

If you want to look over a collection but the way it is populated is different then this is also a possibility. For this example I'm populating a pl/sql collection in 2 different ways depending on the value of an argument and then looping through the collection once.

```
create or replace PROCEDURE list_employees2 (some_input_variable VARCHAR2)
AS
  TYPE emp_t  IS TABLE OF emp.ename%TYPE INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;
  t_emp emp_t;
BEGIN
  IF some_input_variable = 'A' THEN
    SELECT ename 
      BULK COLLECT INTO t_emp 
      FROM emp WHERE hiredate > DATE'1982-01-01';
  ELSIF some_input_variable = 'B' THEN
    t_emp(1) := 'KOEN';
    t_emp(2) := 'MIKE';
  END IF;
  FOR i IN 1 .. t_emp.COUNT LOOP
    dbms_output.put_line(t_emp(i));
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Comment: That doesn´t help. I can not ask for null values. To specify, in my first select i want to iterate through some rows that are returned by a function. That function for example returns all employees starting with the letter B. In my 2nd select i dont call that function and just select all names of the employees but that is just a really basic example of what the function really does.

Comment: Ok, that is different from your original question where you have the same statement with a different where clause - which is what I answered. I updated my answer for a case where the data is populated in 2 very different ways.