# String concatenation select query is not giving result pl/sql script

Tags: oracle, plsql, concatenation

I am trying to construct query dynamically but after string concatenation the select statement not producing any result in pl/sql.

Please help me on this

```
DECLARE
  person_id NUMBER;
BEGIN
  DECLARE
    age_where VARCHAR2(100 CHAR);
    TEMP_WHERE     VARCHAR2(100 CHAR) := '';
    add_temp_where BOOLEAN            := true;
    
  begin
    age_where := q'[ and age=28]';
    
    IF(ADD_TEMP_WHERE) THEN
      TEMP_WHERE := age_where;
    END IF;
    
  SELECT id INTO person_id FROM PERSON WHERE name = 'David' || TEMP_WHERE ;
  EXCEPTION
  WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('no data');
  END;
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('result : ' || person_id);
END;
```

Table entries

```
ID      NAME        AGE     ADDRESS     SALARY
-----------------------------------------------
1       David       28      PURAM       30000
2       Vimal       30      MARUR       20000
```

Output:

```
anonymous block completed
no data
result :
```

Comment: You will have to use `execute immediate` to run dynamic SQL. Also a *hint*  use **bind variables** instead of predicate string concatenation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need dynamic SQL for that.

```
SQL> DECLARE
  2     person_id       NUMBER;
  3     age_where       VARCHAR2 (100 CHAR);
  4     TEMP_WHERE      VARCHAR2 (100 CHAR) := '';
  5     add_temp_where  BOOLEAN := TRUE;
  6     l_str           VARCHAR2 (400);
  7  BEGIN
  8     age_where := q'[ and age=28]';
  9
 10     IF (ADD_TEMP_WHERE)
 11     THEN
 12        TEMP_WHERE := age_where;
 13     END IF;
 14
 15     l_str := q'[SELECT id FROM PERSON WHERE name = 'David']' || TEMP_WHERE;
 16
 17     EXECUTE IMMEDIATE l_str
 18        INTO person_id;
 19
 20     DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('result : ' || person_id);
 21  END;
 22  /
result : 1

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your objective is to have dynamic predicate in a query, based on input parameters. This is a frequent task.

The most important think is to realize, that you should always use **bind variables** for production queries, i.e. *ommit* construction such as `WHERE name = 'David' || TEMP_WHERE`.

There are three options in PL/SQL

**Use IF - ELSE**

This is the simplest option where for each combination of the input parameter there is one IF/ELSE branch

```
declare
 l_person_id  int;
 l_name varchar2(10) := 'David';
 l_age int := 28;
 add_temp_where int := 1; 
begin
  if add_temp_where = 0 then
    select id into l_person_id from person where name = l_name;
  else
    select id into l_person_id from person where name = l_name and age = l_age;
  end if;  
  dbms_output.put_line(l_person_id);    
end;
/
```

This will work in your case with one optional parameter, but is not practicable with more parameters. For 3 parameters you will need 8 branches.

**Use OR to Disable Predicates**

This option use only one *static* statement and use the `OR` logic to disable unwanted parameters.

Note that I'm using the parameter `add_temp_where` and `int` 0,1 to be able to use it in SQL.

```
declare
 l_person_id  int;
 l_name varchar2(10) := 'David';
 l_age int := 28;
 add_temp_where int := 1; 
begin
  select id into l_person_id from person where name = l_name and (add_temp_where = 0 or age = l_age);
  dbms_output.put_line(l_person_id);    
end;
/
```

So basically if `add_temp_where = 0` than the predicate `age = l_age` is ignored due to shortcut evaluation.

This option works fine in case that *for all options the query returns similar number of rows* (technically the same execution plan is used).

It *fails badly* in case that for one option the whole table is returned and for other ony some small part (via index).

In such case you need to use dynamic SQL.

**Dynamic SQL**

You use the same *trick* as above with `OR`, so you generate following SQL strings

```
-- for  add_temp_where = 1
select id  from person where name = :1 and age = :2
-- for  add_temp_where = 0
select id  from person where name = :1 and (0=0 or age = :2)'
```

Note that both statement have two bind variables, so they can be used in one `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` as follows:

```
declare
 l_person_id  int;
 l_name varchar2(10) := 'David';
 l_age int := 28;
 add_temp_where BOOLEAN := true;
 --
 l_sql1 varchar2(1000) := 'select id  from person where name = :1 and age = :2';
 l_sql2 varchar2(1000) := 'select id  from person where name = :1 and (0=0 or age = :2)'; 
begin
  execute immediate l_sql1 into l_person_id using l_name, l_age;
  dbms_output.put_line(l_person_id); 
  execute immediate l_sql2 into l_person_id using l_name, l_age;
  dbms_output.put_line(l_person_id);   
end;
/
```

Both statements are independent and can have therefore different execution plans, which solves the problem of the second option.

More info and credits to this option [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57895363/4808122) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57653954/4808122)

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion @Marmite Bomber