# Query in a procedure with many parameters

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, parameters, sys-refcursor

There is a stored procedure that returns sys_refcursor.
The code for this procedure is: (btw, fk and pk are indexed):

```
procedure GET_SMTH(
  res_cv_out out sys_refcursor,
  <in parameters>)
is
begin
  open res_cv_out for
    select
      t1.<some fields>, t2.<some fields>, <etc.>
    from
      table1 t1
        left outer join
      table2 t2
        on t1.pk = t2.fk
        left outer join
      table3 t3
        on t3.pk = t2.fk
       <etc. many(~10) tables>
    where ( param1 is null
            or
            ( param1 is not null and t2.param1 like '%'||param1||'%' )
           )
      and ( param2 is null
            or
            ( param2 is not null and nvl(t2.param2, t3.param2) like '%'||param2||'%' )
           )
      and ( param3 is null
            or
            ( param3 is not null and t3.param3 like '%'||param3||'%' )
           )
      <etc. many(~15) parameters>;
  end;
```

In the table1 table there are about 500kk rows, in the rest, for example, about 500k rows (in some about 1k). About 0.0005% of table1 rows usually satisfy the condition.

If, for example, there is an index on table3.param3 - and only param3 (other parameters is null)
will be passed to the procedure - will it work normally (quickly) (as if only the param3 was in the where section) or not?

That is, for the case described above - Oracle in runtime changes the query above to such (accordingly with the change of the plan) or not? :

```
select
  t1.<some fields>, t2.<some fields>, <etc.>
from
  table1 t1
    left outer join
  table2 t2
    on t1.pk = t2.fk
    left outer join
  table3 t3
    on t3.pk = t2.fk
   <etc. many(~10) tables>
where  t3.param3 like '%'||param3||'%'
```

How is it better to solve such a task?

Comment: Can't you call it with various combinations of parameters to test it; or run the query standalone using bind variables set to various values?

Comment: See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17681428/issue-with-oracle-bind-variables-not-using-index-properly/17702034#17702034) for an example of how to implement this with multiple params.